# I want to permute given input(numbers, string, float etc) to the length(given)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, permutation, python-itertools

My Code, is here you read my problem please and give me better output if you can.

```
import itertools

variable, r = input().split()
r = int(r)
l = list(itertools.permutations(variable,r))
for i in l:
    for j in range(0,r):
        print(f'{i[j]}{i[j+1]}')
```

> If my input is `HACK 2`
>
> My output should like that

```
AC
AH
AK
CA
CH
CK
HA
HC
HK
KA
KC
KH
```

> I get here tuple index error on this line `print(f'{i[j]}{i[j+1]}')`

Comment: You can just replace your inner loop with `print(''.join(i))`

Comment: `i[j+1]` will fail when `j == r-1` in the inner loop since `i` only has `r` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f'{i[j]}{i[j+1]}'
```

This represents two items from `i`. But we want to use all of the items from `i`, however many there are. Say for example that we input `HACK 3`; `itertools.permutations` will produce a permutation like `('H', 'A', 'C')`, and we want to output a single item `'HAC'` - we don't want to loop over this again and get `'HA'`, `'AC'` separately.

What we want to do is simply join up all of the items into a single string. We do that using the built-in `.join` string method:

```
# Also, there is no need to make a list ahead of time; we can iterate directly
# on the itertools results.
for item in itertools.permutations(variable,r):
    print(''.join(item))
    # Another way is to pass the letters as separate argument to `print`,
    # and let it do the joining implicitly:
    # print(*item, sep='')
    # This is one of those neat things that becomes possible due to `print`
    # becoming a function in 3.x.
```

Comment: Thank You! your explanation is very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

The point is that your tuple has only two elements but your index is from 0 to `r` which means inside for series it will be from `0,1,2`. This is creating error tuple out of index

The right for series will be

```
for i in l:
    for j in range(0,r-1):
        print(f'{i[j]}{i[j+1]}')
```

Comment: This is wrong. `r` is the number of values to print. The f-string is hard-coded to print two values, which is not good since `r` can be some other value besides 2.